# packer post-processor "Unknown artifact type" error when combining docker-tag and shell-local

Tags: docker, packer

I have the following packer config file:

```
{
  "builders":[
    {
      "type": "docker",
      "image": "ubuntu:18.04",
      "commit": true
    }

  ],
  "post-processors": [
    [
      {
        "type": "shell-local",
        "inline": ["$(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-2)"]
      },
      {
        "type": "docker-tag",
        "repository": "localhost/my_image",
        "tag": "latest"
      },
      {
        "type": "docker-tag",
        "repository": "123456789.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/my_image",
        "tag": "latest"
      },
      "docker-push"
    ]
  ]
}
```

This gives me the following error

```
==> docker: Running post-processor: shell-local
==> docker (shell-local): Running local shell script: /var/folders/zh/wsr6wlx11v9703__rn7f3b080000gn/T/packer-shell756682313
==> docker (shell-local): WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
    docker (shell-local): Login Succeeded
==> docker: Running post-processor: docker-tag
Build 'docker' errored: 1 error(s) occurred:

* Post-processor failed: Unknown artifact type: 
Can only tag from Docker builder artifacts.
```

It works if I remove the shell-local post-processor.

It also doesn't matter what kind of command I execute in the shell-local post-processor.

I tried to add `"keep_input_artifact": true` to the shell-local post-processor but this did not change anything.

How can I execute a shell-local post-processor before a docker-tag / docker-push post-processor?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I have to put the shell-local post-processor in a separate list, i.e. I have to add another list to the list of post-processors, like so:

```
"post-processors": [
    [
      {
        "type": "shell-local",
        "inline": ["$(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-2)"]
      }
     ],
     [
      {
        "type": "docker-tag",
        "repository": "localhost/my_image",
        "tag": "latest"
      },
      {
        "type": "docker-tag",
        "repository": "123456789.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/my_image",
        "tag": "latest"
      },
      "docker-push"
    ]
  ]
}
```